# SpringBoot: Interceptor's preHandle run twice on streaming endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, streaming, interceptor

I want to use an interceptor to manage the number of currently active connections with the server. Besides the usual JSON endpoints, my API also offers endpoints for streaming bytes. I implemented a session manager, that keeps track of the session count, a limiting interceptor and several API endpoints. Below is some exemplary code.

The usual JSON endpoints are running well with the interceptor. However, the streaming endpoint actually calls the interceptor's `preHandle` method twice, but the `afterCompletion` only once. The second call to `preHandle` happens after the first call's response computation was finished. When I remove the session manager from the interceptor, this behavior does not occur anymore.

Minimal working example:

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final Interceptor interceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(this.interceptor).addPathPatterns("/numbers", "/numbers/*");
    }
}
```

Interceptor:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class Interceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    private final SessionManager sessionManager;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        log.info("Pre-handle {}", this.hashCode());
        return this.sessionManager.accept();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception e) {
        log.info("After completion {}", this.hashCode());
        this.sessionManager.leave();
    }
}
```

Session manager:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class SessionManager {
    private static final int MAX_SESSION_COUNT = 1;
    private final AtomicInteger sessionCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public synchronized boolean accept() {
        int sessionCount = this.sessionCount.get();
        if (sessionCount >= MAX_SESSION_COUNT) {
            log.error("Upper session limit hit! Currently active sessions: {}, maximum allowed active sessions: {}", sessionCount, MAX_SESSION_COUNT);
            return false;
        }
        sessionCount = this.sessionCount.incrementAndGet();
        log.debug("Accept new session. Currently active sessions: {}, maximum allowed active sessions: {}", sessionCount, MAX_SESSION_COUNT);
        return true;
    }

    public void leave() {
        int sessionCount = this.sessionCount.decrementAndGet();
        log.debug("Decrement session count to {}", sessionCount);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/numbers")
@Slf4j
public class Controller {
    private final Random random = new Random();

    @PostMapping("")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Integer>> number() {
        log.info("Generate numbers");
        List<Integer> bytes = IntStream.range(0, 1_000)
                .map(ignored -> this.random.nextInt(255))
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(bytes);
    }

    @PostMapping("/stream")
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> numberStream() {
        log.info("Generate stream start");
        StreamingResponseBody responseBody = outputStream -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
                outputStream.write(this.random.nextInt(255));
            }
        };
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .body(responseBody);
    }
}
```

I found [a similar topic on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67881572/handlerinterceptor-prehandle-called-twice), but the advice given there does not work in my case. The behavior does not change when removing `@Component` from my interceptor and instantiating interceptor and session manager manually in the `addInterceptors` method.

Log (maximum session count = 2):

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.1)

2021-12-10 14:21:25.999  INFO 17112 --- [           main] c.e.untitled2.Untitled2Application       : Starting Untitled2Application using Java 1.8.0_312 on HOSTNAME with PID 17112 (D:\IntelliJProjects\untitled2\target\classes started by USERNAME in D:\IntelliJProjects\untitled2)
2021-12-10 14:21:26.001  INFO 17112 --- [           main] c.e.untitled2.Untitled2Application       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-12-10 14:21:26.626  INFO 17112 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-12-10 14:21:26.632  INFO 17112 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-12-10 14:21:26.632  INFO 17112 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.55]
2021-12-10 14:21:26.701  INFO 17112 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-12-10 14:21:26.701  INFO 17112 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 669 ms
2021-12-10 14:21:26.907  INFO 17112 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-12-10 14:21:26.913  INFO 17112 --- [           main] c.e.untitled2.Untitled2Application       : Started Untitled2Application in 1.197 seconds (JVM running for 1.84)
#### Call /numbers
2021-12-10 14:21:49.494  INFO 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-12-10 14:21:49.494  INFO 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-12-10 14:21:49.494  INFO 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
2021-12-10 14:21:49.502  INFO 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.example.untitled2.Interceptor        : Interceptor 1184674729 pre-handles request 1068123396: POST /numbers
2021-12-10 14:21:49.503  INFO 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.example.untitled2.SessionManager     : Accept new session. Currently active sessions: 1, maximum allowed active sessions: 2
2021-12-10 14:21:49.508  INFO 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.example.untitled2.Controller         : Generate numbers
2021-12-10 14:21:49.536  INFO 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.example.untitled2.Interceptor        : After completion 1184674729
2021-12-10 14:21:49.536  INFO 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.example.untitled2.SessionManager     : Decrement session count to 0
#### Call /numbers again
2021-12-10 14:21:57.054  INFO 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] com.example.untitled2.Interceptor        : Interceptor 1184674729 pre-handles request 1068123396: POST /numbers
2021-12-10 14:21:57.054  INFO 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] com.example.untitled2.SessionManager     : Accept new session. Currently active sessions: 1, maximum allowed active sessions: 2
2021-12-10 14:21:57.054  INFO 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] com.example.untitled2.Controller         : Generate numbers
2021-12-10 14:21:57.055  INFO 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] com.example.untitled2.Interceptor        : After completion 1184674729
2021-12-10 14:21:57.055  INFO 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] com.example.untitled2.SessionManager     : Decrement session count to 0
#### Call /numbers/stream
2021-12-10 14:22:06.375  INFO 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] com.example.untitled2.Interceptor        : Interceptor 1184674729 pre-handles request 1068123396: POST /numbers/stream
2021-12-10 14:22:06.376  INFO 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] com.example.untitled2.SessionManager     : Accept new session. Currently active sessions: 1, maximum allowed active sessions: 2
2021-12-10 14:22:06.376  INFO 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] com.example.untitled2.Controller         : Generate stream start
2021-12-10 14:22:06.414  INFO 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] com.example.untitled2.Interceptor        : Interceptor 1184674729 pre-handles request 317286159: POST /numbers/stream
2021-12-10 14:22:06.414  INFO 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] com.example.untitled2.SessionManager     : Accept new session. Currently active sessions: 2, maximum allowed active sessions: 2
2021-12-10 14:22:06.416  INFO 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] com.example.untitled2.Interceptor        : After completion 1184674729
2021-12-10 14:22:06.416  INFO 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] com.example.untitled2.SessionManager     : Decrement session count to 1
#### Call /numbers/stream again
2021-12-10 14:22:17.857  INFO 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] com.example.untitled2.Interceptor        : Interceptor 1184674729 pre-handles request 1068123396: POST /numbers/stream
2021-12-10 14:22:17.857  INFO 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] com.example.untitled2.SessionManager     : Accept new session. Currently active sessions: 2, maximum allowed active sessions: 2
2021-12-10 14:22:17.857  INFO 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] com.example.untitled2.Controller         : Generate stream start
2021-12-10 14:22:17.889  INFO 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] com.example.untitled2.Interceptor        : Interceptor 1184674729 pre-handles request 1473864520: POST /numbers/stream
2021-12-10 14:22:17.889 ERROR 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] com.example.untitled2.SessionManager     : Upper session limit hit! Currently active sessions: 2, maximum allowed active sessions: 2
#### Call /numbers/stream again
2021-12-10 14:22:26.443  INFO 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] com.example.untitled2.Interceptor        : Interceptor 1184674729 pre-handles request 1068123396: POST /numbers/stream
2021-12-10 14:22:26.443 ERROR 17112 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] com.example.untitled2.SessionManager     : Upper session limit hit! Currently active sessions: 2, maximum allowed active sessions: 2
```

The logs show that `preHandle` is called twice while `afterCompletion` is called only once.

Comment: Can you check what is the HTTP method you get in the interceptor? If one of the requests has the HTTP OPTIONS method, you can ignore the OPTIONS call.

Comment: Both HTTP requests are `POST /numbers/stream`. The hash code of the interceptor is identical between both calls, the hash code of the request is not. That means, we have two different request instances, but only one interceptor instance.

Comment: Can you post the application logs from the app start to the interceptor invocation? Trying to identify how many instances of the interceptor is getting created and how the 2 invocations differs.

Comment: Ok, I'll add the log.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So to start with the issue which you are having we need to start with the dispatch types supported by the Servlet environment and particularly the ASYNC dispatch type which was added as part of the Servlet 3.0 specification. In a nutshell, the ASYNC dispatch type was added to support long-running / heavy requests which in older times were blocking the servlet container from handling other requests, as the handler thread was blocked waiting for the heavy/long-running task to be finished. So clever guys out there decided that the long-running and heavy jobs can be executed in a parallel thread and the main worker thread can be released to the pool so new small requests can be handled.

So let's get back to your issue:
So have two endpoints one returning the JSON or a simple object which can be handled by the handler thread and the second one which returns the `StreamingResponseBody`. For the first one, no special handling is defined, so Spring handles the request as a usual request and just generates a payload and returns it back to the client. For the second one spring has a custom response handler called `StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler` which basically creates a ASYNC version of the request (coping all of the attributes but changing the dispatch type) and pushes the execution to the new thread via `WebAsyncManager`.

So why does the `preHandle()` called twice ? That is because once it is called as part of the first execution based on the `REQUEST` dispatch and just after pre handle Spring starts handling the request and understands that it should be handled in `ASYNC` mode as the return type is a stream (basically unsized thing), so a copy of the request is made it it is once again executed in the new thread. So if you look into `preHandle()` you will notice that it is called from different threads, with the same request data but different dispatch type on request.

More info here:

[Github Issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/17209)

[Code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/18039785aeacc3ca76c70014b11fb30923a54941)

So what you can do ?
Your `Interceptor` should be a bit clever to not blindly call `sessionManager.accept();` but check if the request was already handled before.

So very dummy version will look like this

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class Interceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    private final SessionManager sessionManager;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        log.info("Pre-handle {}", this.hashCode());
        if(BooleanUtils.isTrue(request.getAttribute("accepted")) || DispatcherType.ASYNC == request.getDispatcherType()){
            return true;
        }
        boolean accepted = this.sessionManager.accept();
        if (accepted){
            request.setAttribute("accepted", true);
        }
        return accepted;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception e) {
        log.info("After completion {}", this.hashCode());
        this.sessionManager.leave();
    }
}
```

Comment: The behavior described in the answer is referenced in [this gitthub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/17209) and documented in the [source code itself](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/18039785aeacc3ca76c70014b11fb30923a54941).

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation and the suggestion. I already played around with the thought of using a set to record already seen requests, but I was convinced there must be a better solution to this problem. Setting an attribute of the request seems such a better solution. I'll try it out later.

Comment: @Babl The `BooleanUtils` class you're using is from `org.apache.commons.lang3`?

Comment: @Green nahh )) Something custom ...

Comment: Ok, I see. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html#afterCompletion-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Exception-)

> Note: Will only be called if this interceptor's preHandle method has successfully completed and returned true!

`afterCompletion()` method will be called only if the `preHandle()` method returns `true`. In your case, you are incrementing the session count and returning false.

If you want to call `sessionManager.leave();` always(irrespective of what the preHandle() returns), use the `postHandle()` instead of `afterCompletion()`.

Comment: This explains why `afterCompletion` is called only once when I increase the limit. However, I would expect that `preHandle` will be called once for every request, not twice. The problem with this behaviour is that `preHandle` is called twice before `afterCompletion` is called.

Comment: I updated the logs with session count = 2 and printing a log message when increasing/decreasing the active session count. Apparently, `preHandle` returns true if and only if I increase the session count. Consequently, I think `afterCompletion` is the right location to call `sessionManager.leave()`.